# Looping through table hierarchy in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

I am doing some reporting over the structure of access for a given set of Pages in an Application. 
These Pages are grouped together into Abilities. If an ID has any one of the Pages for this Ability I want to record the Ability id and the id once, even though they may have several Pages giving access.
With the code below it is writing out each User(id) thousands of times, overloading the site and filling up the table. 
I know the logic is flawed, but I was hoping that by doing a select in the loop to check if an id and ability exist (skipping over the insert) that I could eliminate duplicate entries into the table. It is not working and I am sure this can be more streamlined:

```
 $ability_page_details1 = $DB_con2->prepare("SELECT PGD FROM PGD_DETAILS WHERE PGD = :pgd_ability1 AND SELECT_FLAG = 'Y'"); 
     $ability_page_details1->bindParam(':pgd_ability1', $pgd_ability1); 
     $ability_page_details1->execute(); 

     while($ability_content_page_row = $ability_page_details1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 

     $pgd_page1 = $ability_content_page_row['PGD']; 
     //this is the page 



       //now lets work out all the Abilities that have this page 

     $ability_page_compare1 = $DB_con2->prepare("SELECT PGD.PNLNAME, AUTH.PNLITEMNAME,  
        PGD.SELECT_FLAG, AUTH.ACTIONS, AUTH.ID FROM PPGD INNER JOIN AUTH ON  
        PGD.PGDNAME = AUTH.PGDNAME WHERE PGD.PGDNAME = :pgdname_page1 AND AUTH.ACTIONS >0"); 
     $ability_page_compare1->bindValue(':pgdname_page1', $pgdname_page1); 
     $ability_page_compare1->execute(array(':pgdname_page1'=>$pgdname_page1)); 

     while($ability_page_compare_row1 = $ability_page_compare1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
     $id_ability1 = $ability_page_compare_row1['ID'];
```

//lets check if the ID has an entry already, if not then insert

```
               $check_pm_for_abilities = $DB_con2->prepare("SELECT id, ability_id FROM validation_abilities WHERE id =:id"); 
      $check_pm_for_abilities->execute(array(":id" => $id_ability1));     

      $check_pm_for_abilities_row=$check_pm_for_abilities->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

      if($check_pm_for_abilities_row['classid']==$id_ability1 && $check_pm_for_abilities_row['ability_id']==$ability_id1) { 

      } 
      else{
```

//now for the insert

```
   $validation_abilities = $DB_con2->prepare("INSERT INTO validation_abilities (id, validation_id, ability_id) 
      VALUES(:id, :validation_id, :ability_id)"); 
      $validation_abilities->execute(array(":id" => $id_ability1, ":validation_id"=>$validation_id, ":ability_id"=>$ability_id1)); 
      }
```

Comment: Please mention which query language you are using..

Comment: PDO in this instance